# Instantiating Flyte task to create workflow at runtime

Tags: python, flyte

Is it possible to instantiate a Flyte Task at runtime so that I can create a Workflow with a variable number of Tasks and with each Task running a runtime-determined Python callable? In the [documentation](https://docs.flyte.org/projects/cookbook/en/stable/auto/core/flyte_basics/task.html), I only see references to compile-time Workflows that are declaratively composed of Python function annotated with the `@Task` decorator.

If you can provide any existing examples in open source code or a new, small inline example, please do! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality I was looking for is provided by the [`FlyteRemote` class](https://docs.flyte.org/projects/flytekit/en/latest/design/control_plane.html#registering-entities). With this class, one can register instantiated entities, i.e. tasks, workflows, and launchplans.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at dynamic workflows https://docs.flyte.org/projects/cookbook/en/stable/auto/core/control_flow/dynamics.html.
Dynamic in Flyte is like JITing in a language like Java. The new workflow graph is created, compiled, verified and then executed. But the graph is created in response to the inputs and you control the shape / structure at runtime

Comment: Even within a `@dynamic` workflow, the tasks have to be defined at compile time. The shape of the workflow is configurable, but the tasks of the workflow must be defined at compile time. They are configurable in the sense that you can pass parameters to the tasks, but you cannot instantiate a task at runtime. For example, I want to fetch SQL from a database and then run a [Snowflake](https://docs.flyte.org/projects/flytekit/en/latest/plugins/generated/flytekitplugins.snowflake.SnowflakeTask.html) with that SQL. The Snowflake must know the SQL at compile time.